# Data is not appearing in chart in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

I have not been able to figure out why the dataset I load does not appear in the chart I created in Google Earth Engine. I am new to GEE and JavaScript in general, so I may be missing something obvious. I created a buffer that I want the data pulled from and show up in the chart. I also have two charts created for different time periods in the dataset. A few data points show up for the "winter chart" but none in the "summer chart".

```
   var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("OSU/GIMP/ICE_VELOCITY_OPT");
   var midgard = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-37.32658582874774, 66.895336960199],
      [-37.32658582874774, 66.37689364195774],
      [-35.69511610218524, 66.37689364195774],
      [-35.69511610218524, 66.895336960199]]], null, false);
    var red = ee.Geometry.Point([-36.838012316827125, 
    66.40520627951635])
    
    //Winter speed
    var wMagnitude = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.date('1985-10-01', '2016-05-31'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10, 5, 'month'))
    .filterBounds(midgard);
    function clip (image){
    return image.clip(midgard);}
   var clipped = wMagnitude.map(clip);
   var wSpeed = clipped.map (function(image){
   var winterIceSpeed = image.expression(
   'sqrt (x**2+y**2)',{
   'x': image.select('velocity_x'),
   'y': image.select('velocity_y')
   }).rename('winterSpeed')
   .log10();
   var time = image.get('system:time_start');
  return winterIceSpeed.set ('system:time_start', time);});
  var vizParamsMag = {transparency: '0.5',
  min: 1,
  max: 3.7,
  palette:['FFFFFF','f98686','FCD163','0dca00','08c6ff','5600ff','f904f1','803034']
  };
 Map.setCenter(-36.63,66.49, 8); 
 print(wSpeed,'Winter speed');
 Map.addLayer(wSpeed, vizParamsMag,'winterSpeed');
 
 //Summer Speed
 var sMagnitude =dataset
 .filter(ee.Filter.date('1985-06-01', '2016-09-30'))
 .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,9,'month'))
 .filterBounds(midgard);
 function clip (image){
 return image.clip(midgard);}
 var clipped2 = sMagnitude.map(clip);
 var sSpeed = clipped2.map (function(image){
 var summerIceSpeed = image.expression(
 'sqrt (x**2+y**2)',{
  'x': image.select('velocity_x'),
  'y': image.select('velocity_y')
  }).rename('summerSpeed')
 .log10();
 var time2 = image.get('system:time_start');
 return summerIceSpeed.set ('system:time_start', time2);});
 var vizParamsMag2 = {transparency: '0.5',
 min: 1,
 max: 3.7,
 palette:['FFFFFF','f98686','FCD163','0dca00','08c6ff','5600ff','f904f1','803034']
 };
 print (sSpeed,'summer speed');
 Map.addLayer(sSpeed, vizParamsMag2, 'Summer speed');
 
 // red Buffer
 var redBuffer = [ee.Feature(red)]; print (redBuffer,'redbuffer');
 var redBuffered = ee.FeatureCollection(redBuffer);
 var rBuffered = redBuffered.map(function(f) {
 return f.buffer(1500);  
 });
 Map.addLayer(rBuffered, {color: 'red'}, 'redbuffer');
 
//red buffer charts
//clipping to collection for winter and summer
var wRedClipCollection = wSpeed.map(function(img){return img.clipToCollection(rBuffered)});
var sRedClipCollection = sSpeed.map(function(img){return img.clipToCollection(rBuffered)});
print (wRedClipCollection,'winterRedBufferClipped'); 
print(sRedClipCollection,'summerRedBufferClipped');

//creating the chart for winter of red buffer
var wRedBufferChart =
 ui.Chart.image
     .seriesByRegion({
       imageCollection: wRedClipCollection,
       band: 'winterSpeed',
       regions: midgard,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 30,
      seriesProperty: 'label',
      xProperty: 'system:time_start'
    })
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Winter Ice Speed at Red Buffer',
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Winter Ice Speed',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
      },
      lineWidth: 5,
      colors: ['f0af07', '0f8755', '76b349'],
    });
  print(wRedBufferChart);
//creating the chart for summer of red buffer
var sRedBufferChart =
ui.Chart.image
    .seriesByRegion({
      imageCollection: sRedClipCollection,
      band: 'summerSpeed',
      regions: midgard,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 30,
      seriesProperty: 'label',
      xProperty: 'system:time_start'
    })
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Summer Ice Speed at Red Buffer',
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Summer Ice Speed',
        titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
      },
      lineWidth: 5,
      colors: ['f0af07', '0f8755', '76b349'],
    });
   print(sRedBufferChart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but don't you want to plot the timeseries for the redPointBuffer? I assume that is a point on your glacier so I manually placed a point. Then you have a full time series: https://code.earthengine.google.com/19aaa0c685ed580fcf81bace61334761

Else you probably have to provide the location for your feature Red (it isn't defined in your example)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include that in my example, but I did have a point for the red buffer. I edited the example